# Stata: calculating averages over time

Tags: stata

I need to do the following calculation for 20 periods and did not get along with the `forval` command, since I'm just learning how to handle Stata.

This is what I need to repeat for 20 periods:

```
egen avg1 = mean(price1) if  Period == 1
egen avg2 = mean(price2) if  Period == 1
gen AVG = avg1+avg2
gen AVG_t1=AVG/2
drop avg1 avg2 AVG
```

and tried to solve it using `forval`:

```
    sort Period
local j = Period
forval j = 1/20 { 
     egen avg1 = mean(price1) if  Period == `j' 
     egen avg2 = mean(price2) if  Period == `j'
     gen AVG = avg1+avg2 if  Period == `j' 
     gen AVG_t`j'=AVG/2 if  Period == `j'  
     drop avg1 avg2 AVG if Period == `j' 
}
```

Comment: What does "did not get along" mean? The better your description of the problem is, the better your answers will be. Did you get error messages or just unexpected results?

Comment: In Stata, the preferred way of working with subsets of data is through the `by:` prefix. See `help by` and [Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004) by Nick Cox.

Answer (score 2):

Study the help for `egen` to see that it is more flexible than you think.

```
 egen avg1 = mean(price1), by(Period) 
 egen avg2 = mean(price2), by(Period) 
 gen AVG_t1 = (avg1 + avg2) / 2
```

Your loop will fail because second time around `avg1` already exists. What is documented is

```
 bysort Period: egen avg1 = mean(price1) 
 by Period: egen avg2 = mean(price2)
```

but the syntax above will work.